# GDAX websocket freezing

Tags: node.js, gdax-api

I'm trying to create a simple algorithmic trader using the node.js GDAX library. I have an implementation that works fairly well however the websocket is randomly freezing with no close event emitted.i have searched the forums but cannot find a solution to this, my only guess is that the server is ceasing to emit messages as the close event is not transmitted.

I'm fairly new to node.js and websocket so I'm not even sure where to look.

FYI I have code that will automatically re-connect the socket on close but I'm not sure how to implement this if I don't have a trigger event.

Answer (score 0):

Have asked gdax/coinbase support about this in the past. My own theory was they issued some update, the server was updated and the connection broken. Therefore coinbase's solution was to also monitor the heartbeat channel. There really isn't a great alternative solution in place at the moment.